# this.props.history.push with state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm programing a web site for my association under React and I have something I can't resolve despite my research. It's my first project under React and I'm learning by myself.

In 'App', I have some Route that working well
One of them is 'Login', one is 'Subscription' and one is 'Member'.
'Member' component is like 'App' with other Route only for members connected.

- App

  - Route Subscription
  - Route Login
  - Other Public Routes
  - Route Member (seen only if connected)

    - Route Account
    - Other Members Routes

The 'Subscription' component has a state 'step' and show only the current step (a list of questions).

When a member login, a redirection is made to a member page depending of the account status.
If the member login with a temporary password, he is redirected to the password step of 'Subscription' with

```
this.props.history.push({pathname: "/Subscription", state: {step: "password"}});
```

This is working well.

Now, I want to do the same redirection from 'Account' component when the user click on an edit field to change his password then I used the same code. But this is not working. I'm correctly redirected to 'Subscription' but on the first step and not on the "password" step.

As I can see, the state step is lost and become undefined when I do this from 'Account' component.
If I move 'Account' from 'Members' to 'App', this works.

I think that it's because 'Account' and 'Subscription' are not on the same level unlike 'Login' and 'Subscription' that are directly under 'App' but I don't know where the state is lost and I don't know what to do to pass the state correctly in this case. I also don't want to move 'Account' directly under 'App'.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Please update your question to include all the relevant routing/navigation code as well as these components you are trying to redirect from/to. We can't really diagnose/debug code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue.
Despite what I thought, when history.push is used, state is not throwing to the called component but only to the parent of the component where history.push is used.
In my case, when I use history.push from Account, the state is sent to Member component then when I'm redirected to Subscription, I have not the state anymore as it's not a child of Member.

To solve my case, I have configure a state in App and I update this state by passing a function from App to Member to Account then, when I call Subscription, I send the state from App.

I heard about Redux but as I learn React, I like to do everything by myself before using a third party library that does not help me understand how it realy works.